# Oracle Identify Data Type

Tags: oracle, types

Is there an Oracle function to return the data type of the parameter?

Alternatively, what is the easiest way to determine the data type of all columns in a query that I've written?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [Dump](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96540/functions38a.htm#77280) Function:

> **returns a VARCHAR2 value containing the datatype code**, length in bytes, and internal representation of expr. The returned result is always in the database character set. For the datatype corresponding to each code, see Table 2-1.

Comment: And to think... I wrote a PL/SQL program to dump the results of a query into a temporary table, then read the information back from USER_TABLE_COLUMNS.

Answer (score 5):

If you've written a query, you could create a view based on it and then query the data dictionary to see what the columns' data types are:

```
create view vw_test as
select 1       an_integer,
       'abc'   a_string,
       sysdate a_date
from dual;

desc vw_test;

Name        Null     Type
----------- -------- ------------------
AN_INTEGER           NUMBER
A_STRING             CHAR(3)
A_DATE               DATE
```

I'm guessing, however, you want some kind of generic way of determining this at runtime. This method would not be very useful since it involves DDL. In which case DBMS_SQL may help you:

[From the DBMS_SQL Doc:](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sql.htm#i997238)

```
DECLARE
  c           NUMBER;
  d           NUMBER;
  col_cnt     INTEGER;
  f           BOOLEAN;
  rec_tab     DBMS_SQL.DESC_TAB;
  col_num    NUMBER;
  PROCEDURE print_rec(rec in DBMS_SQL.DESC_REC) IS
  BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('col_type            =    '
                         || rec.col_type);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('col_maxlen          =    '
                         || rec.col_max_len);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('col_name            =    '
                         || rec.col_name);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('col_name_len        =    '
                         || rec.col_name_len);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('col_schema_name     =    '
                         || rec.col_schema_name);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('col_schema_name_len =    '
                         || rec.col_schema_name_len);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('col_precision       =    '
                         || rec.col_precision);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('col_scale           =    '
                         || rec.col_scale);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT('col_null_ok         =    ');
    IF (rec.col_null_ok) THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('true');
    ELSE
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('false');
    END IF;
  END;
BEGIN
  c := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;

  DBMS_SQL.PARSE(c, 'SELECT * FROM scott.bonus', DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);

  d := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE(c);

  DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS(c, col_cnt, rec_tab);

/*
 * Following loop could simply be for j in 1..col_cnt loop.
 * Here we are simply illustrating some of the PL/SQL table
 * features.
 */
  col_num := rec_tab.first;
  IF (col_num IS NOT NULL) THEN
    LOOP
      print_rec(rec_tab(col_num));
      col_num := rec_tab.next(col_num);
      EXIT WHEN (col_num IS NULL);
    END LOOP;
  END IF;

  DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(c);
END;
/
```

Comment: Actually, I just wanted to confirm the implicit type conversion rules in a query.  However, this approach will most likely be useful as my database design (and eventually database) matures.