# How can I see the datatype of a column returned by an SQL query?

Tags: sql, oracle, types

I have a query of the form

```
select id, extract(xml, 'Foo/Bar/text()') value 
from mytable;
```

This query runs fine in SQL Developer, and returns what appears to be a char column.

However, the software that is calling this this query, isn't playing well with it, and is throwing the error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError - oracle/xdb/XMLType
```

So in order to debug this, I'm wanting to know what exact datatype that extract statement is returning.

Is this possible?

Comment: I believe you can find your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087161/oracle-identify-data-type

Comment: Does sql developer not allow you to see table definitions?  It does when I use it.  If it's a permissions issue, talk to your dba.

Comment: You can also use the CAST function to convert it to varchar2

Comment: @kazerm - Yes I checked that answer. It gives me datatype 58, which I couldn't see it references.

Comment: @OldProgrammer - Thanks a lot that solved the issue for me. If you post that as a answer I'll at least upvote it.

Comment: @dwjohnston Why don'y you use `extractvalue` function instead of `extract` if you want to get the value in the xml node?

Comment: @ntalbs extractvalue is [deprecated](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions061.htm#SQLRF06173)

Comment: Do you want to know the data type of function `EXTRACT` (then the answer is `XMLType`) or do you like to know this for any query?

Comment: The ´EXTRACT´ function returns ´XMLTYPE´ like @Wernfried states (see documentation http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions067.htm#SQLRF00640 where it says *returns an XMLType instance containing an XML fragment* .) Then when you have an `XMLType` object you can get the actual text with member method `GetStringVal()` http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/t_xml.htm#ARPLS71974 (or `GetClobVal()` for larger text) like for example `extract(xml, 'Foo/Bar/text()').GetStringVal()` .

Comment: `extract(..., '.../text()').getStringVal()` ... Bad idea. Try it with ampersands or quotation marks anywhere in the value being extracted.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, `extractValue()` is deprecated. And if you use the `.GetStringVal()` method on your `extract`-ed `xmltype`, you'll end up having `quot;` instead of `"`, `&amp;` instead of `&` and so on. Therefore, now, to the rescue ...

... the `xmlcast()` function!

---

**Example 1 - not what we want**

```
select xmltype('<xx><value>&amp;&quot;</value></xx>').extract('/xx/value')
from dual;
```

... yields a result of `xmltype` type.

**Example 2 - still not what we want**

```
select xmltype('<xx><value>&amp;&quot;</value></xx>').extract('/xx/value').getStringVal()
from dual;
```

... yields a string result of ...

```
<value>&amp;&quot;</value>
```

**Example 3 - close, but still not what we want**

```
select xmltype('<xx><value>&amp;&quot;</value></xx>').extract('/xx/value/text()').getStringVal()
from dual;
```

... yields a string result of ...

```
&amp;&quot;
```

... whereas ...

**Example 4 - the ultimate way**

```
select xmlcast(xmltype('<xx><value>&amp;&quot;</value></xx>').extract('/xx/value') as varchar2(4000))
from dual;
```

... yields the correct string result of ...

```
&"
```